# Chrome New Tab Extension to show the latest visited URL only if it is a repeated visit

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Ideally, when a New Tab is opened, it would show the most recent pages that have been opened at least twice during the last 24 hours. The most visited pages during the last 24 hours before in the list.

The way I'd like the result is more or less as shown in Google Drive - Recent. I mean, as a list:

[image: screenshot Google Drive - Recent]

And NOT as icons:

[image: screenshot not as icons]

Do you know any Google Chrome extension shows in a New Tab the most visited websites during the last 24 hours?

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best workaround extension is [Re-newtab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/re-newtab/ccfjmnfklnaofoggkolocloghafpoccc/related). This is how it looks after configuring it as I wished:

[image: screenshot of extension configured as I like]